# How to continue the object in django get_next/previous_by_date_created and published?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Anyone can help me how to continue the object in Django by `get_next/previous_by_date_created` and published only?

```
>>> obj_4 = Post.objects.get(pk=4)
>>> obj_4.publish
True
>>> obj_4.get_previous_by_date_created()
<Post: Title Post 3>
>>> obj_4.get_previous_by_date_created().publish
False
>>> obj_4.get_previous_by_date_created().pk
3
>>> obj_2 = Post.objects.get(pk=2)
<Post: Title Post 2>
>>> obj_2.publish
True
>>> obj_4.get_next_by_date_created()
<Post: Title Post 5>
>>> obj_4.get_next_by_date_created().publish
True
>>>
```

I need to continue the object by published only. For example:

```
>>> obj_4 = Post.objects.get(pk=4)
>>> obj_4.get_previous_by_date_created_and_published()
<Post: Title Post 2>
```

Other conditions, if we have such as bellow:

```
pk      : [1,    2,     3,     4,     5,    6,    7,     8   ]
publish : [True, False, False, False, True, True, False, True]
```

And then, if i starting from `pk=5`, the output should be `pk=1`.

```
>>> obj_5 = Post.objects.get(pk=5)
>>> obj_5.get_previous_by_date_created_and_published().pk
1
>>>
>>> obj_5.get_previous_by_date_created_and_published().publish
True
>>>
```

Thanks so much before...

**UPDATE SOLVED:**

**1.** `views.py`

```
class DetailPostView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'detail.html'

    def get_previous_by_created_and_published(self):
        prev = Post.objects.filter(
            created__lte=self.get_object().created,
            publish=True
        ).order_by('-created').first()
        return prev

    def get_next_by_created_and_published(self):
        next = Post.objects.filter(
            created__gte=self.get_object().created,
            publish=True
        ).order_by('-created').first()
        return next

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context_data = super(DetailPostView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context_data[
            'get_previous_by_created_and_published'
        ] = self.get_previous_by_created_and_published()
        context_data[
            'get_next_by_created_and_published'
        ] = self.get_next_by_created_and_published()
        return context_data
```

**2.** `templates/detail.html`

```
<ul class="pager">
  <li class="previous">
  {% if get_previous_by_created_and_published %}
    <a href="{% url 'detail_post_page' slug=get_previous_by_created_and_published.slug %}">&larr; Previous</a>
  {% endif %}
  </li>
  <li class="next">
  {% if get_next_by_created_and_published %}
    <a href="{% url 'detail_post_page' slug=get_next_by_created_and_published.slug %}">Next &rarr;</a>
  {% endif %}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what you mean by 'continue the object'. Are you asking for an implementation of `get_previous_by_created_and_published()`?

Comment: it's just an example of a function to implement, of course i'll getting an error if i try `get_previous_by_created_and_published()` from default django..

Comment: It looks like you'll be able to do it with queries. I don't have enough information about your Post model but it'll look something like `Post.objects.filter(created=True, published=True, pk__lt=5)`, where __lte gives pk < 5. This is assuming that `created` and `published` are both boolean fields of your Post model.

Comment: sorry, yup.. how i can implement `get_previous_by_created_and_published()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An implementation which will work is:

```
def get_previous_by_created_and_published(self):
    prev = Post.objects.filter(created__lte=self.created,
                               published=True
                               ).order_by('-created').first()
    return prev
```

Though I'm assuming here that if there are multiple published posts created before this then you'll only want the most recent, as the name of your method suggests.

`get_next_by_created_and_published` will work in a similar manner, though with `__gte` and the ordering flipped.

Comment: im sorry, i mind in my question the `created` is the `DateTimeField`, i''ll update for it..

Comment: Ah, I see. So would you like the most recently published post?

Comment: actually for detail post (`Next` and `Previous` post)